# iTunes store is showing different version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, version

I am facing weird problem for downloading build from `iTunes store`.

I have uploaded new version of application on `iTunes connect`. And that version is showing `Ready For Sale`. See below image :

[image]

But when I went to App Store in iPhone and it is showing old version. See below image :

[image]

What is the problem ? Why this is occurring ? How it can be resolved ?

I know the solution is to upload new version, but it takes 1 / 2 days.

Comment: Actually you need to select option, that is automatically release this version to end users. I think when submit to App Store you selected manually release option. Please check it ...

Comment: Yes.... I didn't checked that which option is selected that time, But assume that I have selected `Manual Release this Version`. Now what should I do? App is showing `Ready For Sale` and there is not showing any option to change selection from `Manual Release this Version` to `Automatically Release this Version`.